# Convert a system of differential equations of 2nd order into first order equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let
>   $$\begin{cases}p'' = -q\\q'' = p
> \end{cases}$$
>   Goal: convert above system into first order equations.

I expressed the system in matrix form. Next, did some calculation and ended up getting $$p' = e^t\quad\text{and}\quad q' = e^{-t}$$

But I doubt what I did is correct. Is there a proper method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with 2 second order equations in two unknowns.  In effect, you have a single vector ODE of the form v'' = some function of v, where v = (p,q).  What you want is something of the form w' = a function of w.  Try letting w = (p, q, u, s), where the new variables u and s are u = p' and s = q'.

Comment: so (p q) ' = [(0 -1), (1,0)] (p q) ?? and then basically I would get exponential answers, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Often I make mistakes in calculations but the idea will hopefully be clear.

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{t}^{2}p &=&-q \\
\partial _{t}^{2}q &=&p
\end{eqnarray*}
Define
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{1} &=&p,\;p_{2}=\partial _{t}p \\
q_{1} &=&q,\;q_{2}=\partial _{t}q
\end{eqnarray*}
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{t}p_{1} &=&p_{2} \\
\partial _{t}p_{2} &=&-q_{1} \\
\partial _{t}q_{1} &=&q_{2} \\
\partial _{t}q_{2} &=&p_{1}
\end{eqnarray*}
or
$$
\partial _{t}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
q_{2} \\
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
q_{1}
\end{array}
\right) =\mathsf{B}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
q_{2} \\
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
q_{1}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf{B} &=&\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right) ,\;\mathsf{B}^{2}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right) =\mathsf{I} \\
\mathsf{I}+\mathsf{B} &=&2\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right) ,\;\mathsf{I}-\mathsf{B}=-2\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0%
\end{array}%
\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
With
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
q_{2} \\
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
q_{1}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{t}\mathbf{x} &=&\mathsf{B}\mathbf{\cdot x} \\
\mathbf{x}(t) &=&\exp [\mathsf{B}t]\mathbf{x}(0)=\{\mathsf{I}+\mathsf{B}t+%
\frac{1}{2}\mathsf{B}^{2}t^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}\mathsf{B}^{3}t^{3}+\cdots
\}\cdot \mathbf{x}(0) \\
&=&\{\mathsf{I}+\mathsf{B}t+\frac{1}{2}\mathsf{I}t^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}\mathsf{B}%
t^{3}+\cdots \}\cdot \mathbf{x}(0) \\
&=&\{\mathsf{I}\cosh t+\mathsf{B}\sinh (t)\}\cdot \mathbf{x}(0) \\
&=&\{\mathsf{I}\frac{e^{t}+e^{-t}}{2}+\mathsf{B}\frac{e^{t}-e^{-t}}{2}%
\}\cdot \mathbf{x}(0) \\
&=&\{\frac{e^{t}}{2}(\mathsf{I}+\mathsf{B})+\frac{e^{-t}}{2}(\mathsf{I}-%
\mathsf{B})\}\cdot \mathbf{x}(0) \\
&=&\{e^{t}\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right) -e^{-t}\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0%
\end{array}%
\right) \}\cdot \mathbf{x}(0)
\end{eqnarray*}
from which you can read off the expressions for $q(t)$ and $p(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

I find laplace tranforms to be the cleanest way for such problems. for example
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsLaplace.aspx